# How to execute multiple concatenated queries?

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I wanted to grant privileges on some selected tables only. So far I could only gather the necessary queries but unable to execute those.

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON drupal.', TABLE_NAME, ' to ''test'';') As queryStrings 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'drupal' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cache%';
```

OUTPUT:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| queryStrings                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_page to 'test';                   |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cachetags to 'test';                    |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_config to 'test';                 |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_data to 'test';                   |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_entity to 'test';                 |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_discovery to 'test';              |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_default to 'test';                |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_render to 'test';                 |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_container to 'test';              |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_toolbar to 'test';                |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_bootstrap to 'test';              |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_menu to 'test';                   |
| GRANT SELECT ON drupal.cache_dynamic_page_cache to 'test';     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there something like `EXECUTE queryStrings;` ?

I tried to store it in a variable like

```
SET @query = CONCAT('GRANT SELECT ON drupal.', TABLE_NAME, ' to ''test'';') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'drupal' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'cache%');
```

But I am getting error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'drupal' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE' at line 1

Comment: Hi, It's 10.3.11-MariaDB

Comment: Have a look at [dynamic queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: I am getting error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'drupal' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE' at line 1
` . Sorry I am a beginner here.

Comment: Honestly, given the likelihood that you won't be executing these every day, I'd just copy and paste the generated queries and run them manually.